# Inserting CSS to Embedded iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I would like to insert a CSS to an iFrame which is external. Is there like scripts that I can execute to update the styling inside the iframe from my wordpress site?

```
<iframe src="//beautydayspa1.gettimely.com/book/embed?blablabla" scrolling="no" id="timelyWidget" style="width:480px;height:500px;border:1px solid #4f606b"></iframe>
```

Comment: is the iframe domain `beautydayspa1.gettimely.com` the same domain as the parent website? do you control the code in both parent and iframe page, or is it a third party?

Comment: I think you're trying to change the appearance of a third party widget, you may need to go through their help/developer documentation, eg https://help.gettimely.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360060668074-How-to-customise-the-online-booking-process-to-reflect-your-brand

Comment: not the same with the parent domain, I have embedded it to my wordpress website. I control the parent page which is my WP site but the iframe page is not.

Comment: I'm going to suggest you won't be able to inject CSS into the iFrame then, cross browser security is going to lock that down.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript `contentWindow` and `contentDocument`, if the domain of the iframe and where your site is hoste, is the same.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).